# If two elements are different there is a functional under where the image is different

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems, hahn-banach-theorem, dual-maps

I have the following exercise in functional analysis:
Let E be a normed space and $x,y$ different vectors. Prove or disprove finding a counterexample that it exist a function $f \in E^*$ such that $f(x) \not= f(y)$.
I tried do define a function on $<x,y> \subset E $ with different images for $x,y$ and than to extend this with hahn Banach to $E$, but I dont know how to define this. Is this statement even true or is there a counter example?

Comment: Why not just create a functional that is non-zero on $x-y$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579456/dual-space-x-separates-points-of-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the statement is true, and your approach is kind of the way to go. But it is better to state the problem in the following equivalent and more useful way:

> Given $x\in E$ there exists $f\in E^*$ such that $f(x)\ne0$.